# In Netbeans 6.9 and 7, how I change the theme (look and feel) to WIndows theme?

Tags: java, netbeans, themes

How/where I change the theme to the Windows theme in Netbeans 6.9 and 7? Currently it's using the Metal theme.

I've searched, but found nothing.

EDIT: When I edit it's the Windows theme, but when I run the program, it's the Metal theme.

Comment: Are you talking about the NetBeans IDE itself, or a program that you created using NetBeans?

Comment: In the execution inside Netbeans and after "compilation".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find netbeans.conf file in $NETBEANS_HOME/etc.

Locate the line starting with `netbeans_default_options=`. 
Add the switch `--laf com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel` to it, before the ending `"`.

Comment: OP question update made my answer out of topic, but I'm leaving this info here anyway if anyone wants to change the **IDE** look and feel (as opposed to Matisse generated Swing applications which can have it's laf set with `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`

Answer (score 2):

[Try this.](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing/LookFeelNative.html)

Comment: I assume you mean that when you're using the Swing UI builder it uses the Windows LAF, but when you actually run your program, it uses Metal. If that's the case, see the link in my answer and note that Metal is the default on all platforms. Your program is unaware that it is being launched by NetBeans.

Comment: please don't just put a bare link.... IMHO stackoverflow is meant to be a standalone site!

Comment: @VineetMenon stackoverflow is not a walled garden. Just look at all the jsFiddle links.

Comment: I don't have any issues with anyone putting links as the answers. But in the long run, it might happen that the link hosting site just closes; then the answer is just waste, how much repo it has received based on its correctness. and I guess that's the reason SE has its own dedicated image hosting site `imghur`.

Comment: It's the web. That happens. Big deal. Anyway, there's always the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20061214094201/http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing/LookFeelNative.html).

Comment: precisely, it doesn't hurt anyone to just copy the excerpts from the source in addition to the link.

Comment: It doesn't hurt anyone to click a link either.

Comment: okay dude....I concede...I just got this info from the moderators at a discussion at meta.SE...anyways....

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans default look and feel is the theme of your Windows operating system. Try changing your Windows theme, look and feel of NetBeans automatically changes.