# NetBeans: How to change the look and feel with respect to Operating System

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, look-and-feel

I developed a small desktop application in Netbeans using Java. The application is working as expected. I developed it under WIN7.

When i run it on Microsoft Windows, the look and feel of UI is similar to Win XP Metal theme and when i run it on MAC it shows me the same theme. I want to change that theme with respect to operating system. Right now the theme is ok for windows i am looking for solution on MAC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046375/in-netbeans-6-9-and-7-how-i-change-the-theme-look-and-feel-to-windows-theme

Comment: It always amazes me that only answers that spoon feed the answer get upvotes. The link to the tutorial directly answers the question. In addition the tutorial tells how you can dynamcially change the LAF at runtime. In addition it has a table of contents that comver many other Swing topics. In general its loaded with helpful information. If the poster was aware of the tutorial there would have been no need to even post this question. "Give somebody a fish and they eat for a day. Teach somebody to fish and they eat for life".

Comment: agreed with you, but in other hands lots of us (`and in most cases include me`) there up-voted OP's question, when OP's accepted concrete users answer,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try{UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());}
catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Swing, then this should work:

```
try {
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
    UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Read the secton from the Swing tutorial on [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for information about setting/changing the LAF.